# What should be our policy on content in user profiles?

Tags: discussion

I have noticed that some users use their profile page to advertise their blog or the books they have written.

Should we have restrictions on what users can include in their profile page? If so, what should they be? If a user is found to be in violation of the restrictions, what should be the consequences?

Comment: Why can't someone be proud of what they've written? As long as they're not spamming posts, it's fine.

Comment: To the downvoters, why don't you reset your votes? The question is clearly important. I know you don't like me, but the question has nothing to do with your liking towards me. I'm saying this because the negative votes have bad effects on readers.

Comment: @Carlo_R: Why is it clearly important? Am I one of the offenders prompting this proposed restriction?

Comment: Downvotes on meta mean disagreement. Come on, you know better.

Comment: @JasonBourne I knew I'd seen that "Your user page belongs to you" somewhere.

Comment: What @simchona said. I've downvoted because I have no objection to users "promoting" themselves on their profile page, not because I disapprove of this question being asked.

Comment: Some things written in profiles seem strange, but none yet seem to me to be objectionable or actionable. Maybe you should give an answer since it seems that there are some objectionable posts to you.

Comment: While on the subject, Carlo; what does *my enthusiasm has finished* in your profile mean? Normally I would take it as 'I no longer care about EL&U, and won't be here any longer', but from context that would seem mistaken. "I'm no longer an amateur"? Or a joke that went over my head?

Comment: @Tim, thank you, I am pleased to hear from you. No, there is no joke in my profile, to which I added `my ... finished` after having asked this legitimate question: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/76876/sounds-which-seem-to-express-a-particular-quality-whatever-words-they-appear  As you probably know, the question was closed and I was suspended for a procedure violation dealing with my comments. Alas, but the question, which was surely an `expert` one, is still blocked and I cannot post my ...

Comment: ... own answer http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phonestheme that I have found after a lot of efforts. So, while I'm waiting ELL starts, I have decided to keep a low profile here.

Answer (score 9):

You can't really decide what users put in their profiles because they're free to insert what they want. It's your profile and you're allowed to publish about anything:

Your blog, your own everyday diary, a picture of your cat, enigmi, the 5th prime number, a funny face, etc.

What you can't include are those things that might create problems: personal attacks against users or mods, links to *bad* sites, etc.

Comment: *Etc.* in such a context rings alarm bells with me: is there a list of what is unacceptable?

Comment: [This MSO question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/98979/does-so-prevent-users-from-embedding-html-image-links-to-pornographic-content-in) covers exactly this. Caution: the images may shock.

Comment: @TimLymington As long as you don't go beyond the common sense, anything is fine.

Comment: Hey, I get royalties on the fifth prime number, so I hope you will all use it more and more.

Comment: @Robusto: I just gave Alenanno's answer its 11th upvote, if that helps.

Comment: @Robusto I think I deserve a percentage at this point.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't characterize such links to blogs or books as *advertisements*; these seem more like a CV to me. Moreover, I wouldn't discourage such links, in fact, I'd encourage them. They tell me more about the people I interact with on ELU, they often point to helpful resources, and they serve to establish community credibility.

There's a difference between "I wrote such-and-such a book," and "Please buy my book." I'd consider the former entirely relevant and apropos. I might consider the latter a little tacky, but I still wouldn't see a need for moderator intervention.